# Switch Tiles to Images instead of Colors when making this 2048 Game

Tags: image, switch-statement

I have replicated this 2048 tutorial. Not I want to make the tiles be images instead. The tutorial can be found at: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/388/build-your-own-2048-with-spritebuilder-and-cocos2d and the last part is a switch-statement. Can someone please help me on how to make these tiles be images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you want to replicate it with images instead, you need to go into the SpriteBuilder, Place your images (All of them) and size them if needed. Turn them all to not visible. Then publish the file and open Xcode. In Xcode, go to the switch statement. Then for each statement, you have to make the image visible in the case  and specify the image so for example. You also must create the variables.

```
CCSprite *imageOne = nil;


Switch (self.value) {
Case 2:
    _imageOne.visable = TRUE;
   imageOne = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"nameofyourimage.png"];
```

And so on for each Case 4-2048 and specifying the variable names for each one.